# why NameError: name 'canvas' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

```
class PLUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__CANVAS_WIDTH = 320
        self.__CANVAS_HEIGHT = 240

        self.__aqd = AirQuality()
        self.__pop_percentage = self.__aqd.get_percent_population()
        self.__pm10 = self.__aqd.get_pm10()
        self.__country_list = self.__aqd.get_countries()


        self.main_window = None
        self.canvas = None

    def draw_piechart(self):

        self.main_window = Tk()

        self.canvas = Canvas(self.main_window,width = self.__CANVAS_WIDTH,height = self.__CANVAS_HEIGHT)

        self.canvas.pack()

        canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=0,extent=36,fill="red")
        canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=36,extent=72,fill="green")
        canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=108,extent=108,fill="yellow")
        canvas.create_arc(400,400,100,100,start=216,extent=144,fill="blue")


        tkinter.mainloop()

plui = PLUI()
plui.draw_piechart()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Post the full error message, including the stack trace. Also, as an aside, stop using double-underscore name-mangling for no discernible reason. That does **not** mean private. Python *doesn't have access modifiers*.

Comment: you have defined `self.canvas`, not `canvas`. You forgot `self.` in few lines of code.

Comment: Typo: change  `canvas.create_arc(...` to `self.canvas.create_arc(...`

Answer (score 1):

Because `canvas` was never defined. This line:

```
self.canvas = Canvas(self.main_window,width = self.__CANVAS_WIDTH,height = self.__CANVAS_HEIGHT)
```

defines it as an attribute on `self`. So change all of the `canvas.create_arc` calls to `self.canvas.create_arc`